# How can i save to hard disk the image inside a webbrowser control even if the webbroswer have ScrollBarsEnable true?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

This is the code i'm using now:

```
int imagescount = 0;
private void SaveImageFromWebBrowser()
{
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(webBrowser1.Width, webBrowser1.Height);
    webBrowser1.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, webBrowser1.Width, webBrowser1.Height));
    bitmap.Save(@"e:\webbrowserimages\wbImage" + imagescount.ToString("D6") + ".bmp",
                System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
    bitmap.Dispose();
    imagescount++;
}
```

The problem is some images are larger and then there are scrollbars other images smaller so the webbroswer not need the scrollbars.
But the large images with the scrollbars the image on the hard disk i see the whole webbroswer control with the scrollbars !

I want to get the whole image in the WebBbrowser control. Only the image to save not the whole control !

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add a reference to your project called: Microsoft.mshtml

Then:

```
int imagescount = 0;
        private void SaveImageFromWebBrowser()
        {
            IHTMLDocument2 doc = (IHTMLDocument2)webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument;
            IHTMLControlRange imgRange = (IHTMLControlRange)((HTMLBody)doc.body).createControlRange();

            foreach (IHTMLImgElement img in doc.images)
            {
                imgRange.add((IHTMLControlElement)img);

                imgRange.execCommand("Copy", false, null);

                using (Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap))
                {
                    bmp.Save(@"e:\webbrowserimages\Image" + imagescount.ToString("D6") + ".bmp",
                             System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
                }
                imagescount++;
            }
        }
```

Working perfect.